# Can't load an image with cvLoadImage();

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

I'm working on Qt and osX.
My code to load an image is:

...

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("Users/myName/Desktop/img1.png",1);
cvNamedWindow("Example", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("Example", image);
```

...

Is something wrong? (I've tried jpg and other formats).

Comment: Which Version of OpenCV / OS X are you using? Are you shure the path to the file is correct? Try "/Users/myName/Desktop/img1.png" and give some feedback. Another thing which comes to my mind is: Why are you using the old C style API?

Comment: Wow, so Qt finally got C bindings?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image exists. You might want to add some error checking after you load the image to see if that is in fact where your issue is.

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("Users/myName/Desktop/img1.png",1); 
if(image == NULL)
    printf("image not loaded \n")
else
    printf("Loaded image size %dx%d \n",image->width(),image->height());
```

Also add `cvWaitKey(0)` after show image.

Answer (score -1):

Try another absolute directory like "C:/Image/abc.jpg". Be sure that the type of image is correct jpg, jpeg, ... 
If it still does not solve your problem, try the latest version of opencv.
hope this help.